# Possible memory leaks

Tags: c++, python, cpython, python-embedding, python-extensions

Could someone check if there is an memory leak? I am confused.

```
PyObject * somefunc(int function_id, int num_params, int * params){
    PyObject * params_list=PyList_New(0);
        for(int i=0; i < num_params; i++){
             PyObject * val = Py_BuildValue("i", params[i]);
             PyList_Append(params_list, val);
             Py_DecRef(val);
        }

        PyObject * arglist = Py_BuildValue("(i,O)",
            function_id, params_list);
         //Should I DecRef(params_list) ??

        return arglist;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try the code?

Comment: I haven't used cpython, but you should probably release the params_list memory at the end of the function, as you suggested.

Comment: what output? Memory leaks doesn't display any output...

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [C API documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue), the `O` format code for `Py_BuildValue` increments the reference count on its argument, so you are leaking a reference to `params_list`.

You can fix this by either adding a `Py_DECREF` call or by using the `N` format code instead, which acts like `O` but takes ownership of its argument.